# How to insert selected dropdownlist value into database using asp.net entity data model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have used below code to first retrieve `category Id` from `category entity` and bind it to the `dropdownlist` that is `DropDownlistCategory` .Now I want to insert that `category ID` from dropdownlist to product entity which contains four columns in the database such as

```
ProductName,CategoryID,QuantityPerUnit and UnitPrice.
```

But while inserting dropdownlist value it will always select the first value from dropdownlist.

Using this :

`prod.CategoryID =   Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue);`

**Is it correct?**

NewProduct.aspx code:-

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCategory" runat="server"CssClass="form-    control" Width="100px"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" >

    </asp:DropDownList>
```

NewProduct.cs code:-

```
    LaunderDBEntities context = new LaunderDBEntities(); 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var categoryId = from cat in context.Categories
                       select new
                       {

                           categoryID = cat.CategoryID,

                       };


        DropDownListCategory.DataSource = categoryId.ToList();
        DropDownListCategory.DataValueField = "categoryID";
        DropDownListCategory.DataTextField = "categoryID";
        DropDownListCategory.DataBind();
    }
    protected void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveProductInfo();
    }


    private void SaveProductInfo()
    {
        Product prod = new Product();
        prod.ProductName = txtProductName.Text;

        prod.CategoryID =   Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListCategory.SelectedValue);

        prod.QuantityPerUnit = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
        prod.UnitPrice =Convert.ToInt32(txtUnitPrice.Text);


        ProductDA prdDa = new ProductDA();
        prdDa.InertProductDetails(prod);

        Label5.Text = "<p style='color:Green;'>Information Successfully saved!</p>";

        Response.Redirect("ProductInfo.aspx");

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **[IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** in page load. Bind dropdown list only when page is load first time.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        { 
             //.... code to bind the dropdownlist

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works..please vote up if my question is helpful.