# I'm trying to insert data from a ASP.NET Webform into database. But I get a foreign key error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a Student Management System using ASP.NET webforms and a database. I've linked database with my project using Entity Framework.

But after I've clicked the "Submit" button, I get a foreign key error.

Here is my code and database diagram:

```
public void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new STUDENT_MANAGEEntities();

    var tb = new Student_Info();

    tb.Student_Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtStudentId.Text.Trim());
    tb.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
    tb.Semester_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdSemester.SelectedIndex);
    tb.Session = txtSession.Text.Trim();
    tb.Department_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdDepartment.SelectedIndex);
    tb.Shift_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdShift.SelectedIndex);
    tb.Gender_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdGender.SelectedIndex);
    tb.Blood_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdBlood.SelectedIndex);
    tb.Birth_Date = clrBirthDate.SelectedDate;
    tb.Contact = txtContact.Text.Trim();
    tb.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();

    db.AddToStudent_Info(tb);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqIwf.jpg)

And this is the error I get:

[image: Error]

Comment: when you have a fpreign key between two tables as you have, then the bloodid has to exist prior to inserting the student, usually sou select the blodtype from a combo box, so that you only enter values that exist and the error will not occur

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: this shows you i believe what i mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390577/how-to-insert-selected-dropdownlist-value-into-database-using-asp-net-entity-dat

Comment: *Assuming* it's the `tb.Blood_Id` column that references `dbo.Blood_Info` via this foreign key constraint - check what value you're trying to insert for `Blood_Id` - does that value exist in the `Blood_Info` table?? It seems you're simply trying to insert a value that doesn't exist in the referenced table

Comment: I've tried this. But this code showing in drop down only the Id. But I want to show Name as like "1st Shift" for Id Value 1; "2nd Shift" for Id Value 2. Hope you'll understand. @nbk

Comment: @marc_s referenced table have exact value which I want to insert. But though it's not working. Can we talk via any social media?

Comment: you need only the bloodtyoeid to insert into your student table, as text for the elenet you take the Text value, i think you have all there waht you need, and so you  never have an id that doesn't fit

Comment: The problem is likely due to the use of `dpdBlood.SelectedIndex` to set `tb.Blood_Id`. The selected index is a 0-based number that indicates which item in the drop down list a user has selected - 0 being the first, 1 being second and so on. That index may have nothing to do with the `Blood_Id` of the selected item so it may not exist in the `Blood_Info` table. Have you looked at other properties of the list control, such as `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the `SelectedIndex` and using that for the FK. `SelectedIndex` is just the position in the list of items that was selected, so 0,1,2,3,4,... The values in your drop down likely have different ID values, and you may even have them sorted by name etc. so the IDs might be 4,1,2,5,3 for example. Selecting the first item in the list might be Blood ID 4, but it's `SelectedIndex` would be 0 which doesn't correspond to any Blood record.

When you populate your Comboboxes based on the lookup tables you need to bind both the Text, and the Value of each item. Value being the Key for that record, I.e. BloodTypeId. Then I believe the `SelectedValue` should give you that bound Value amount, otherwise you might need to cast `SelectedItem` as a `SelectListItem` and get it's `Value`:

```
// try this...
tb.Blood_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dpdBlood.SelectedValue);


// or this...
var selectedItem = (SelectListItem)dpdBlood.SelectedItem;
tb.Blood_Id = Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem.Value);
```

This should be done for *all* drop-downs. Otherwise you will get situations where the values you select don't get saved to the same record (where the index <> the ID) or errors where index doesn't match any ID.

Comment: Thanks to all. That error is solved using SelectedItem.Value instead of SelectedIndex. Again heartiest thanks to all.